# Given $\frac{\log x}{b-c}=\frac{\log y}{c-a}=\frac{\log z}{a-b}$ show that $x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b}\cdot z^{a+b-c} = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given:

$$\dfrac{\log x}{b-c}=\dfrac{\log y}{c-a}=\dfrac{\log z}{a-b}$$

We have to show that :

$$x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b}\cdot z^{a+b-c} = 1$$

I made three equations using cross multiplication :

$$1.~~x^{c-a}=y^{b-c}$$
$$2.~~y^{a-b}=z^{c-a}$$
$$3.~~z^{b-c}=x^{a-b}$$

How do I proceed hereafter? If I multiply the equations, one variable goes away from exponents.

Thank you.

Comment: A couple of answers posted below assume the base of the logarithm is $e$, and that is what is normally presumed when the base is not specified.  However, in this case it doesn't matter what the base is, as long as all three logarithms are to the same base.  I've posted an answer below that shows this. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{\log(x)}{b-c} = \dfrac{\log(y)}{c-a} = \dfrac{\log(z)}{a-b} = t$$
This gives us
$$x=e^{t(b-c)}, y = e^{t(c-a)} \text{ and }z = e^{t(a-b)}$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b} \cdot z^{a+b-c} & = e^{t\left((b-c)(b+c-a) + (c-a)(c+a-b) + (a-b)(a+b-c)\right)}\\
& = e^{t(b^2-c^2-ab+ac + c^2 - a^2 -bc + ba + a^2 - b^2 - ac + bc)} = e^0 = 1
\end{align}

Comment: This is nice! very short method! but can i proceed in way i started? can it be done that way? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use your equations, here is a method.

Multiplying the equations together, we obtain: $$x^{c-a}y^{a-b}z^{b-c}=y^{b-c}z^{c-a}x^{a-b}$$ which gives after reordering: $$x^{b+c-a}y^{c+a-b}z^{a+b-c}=x^a y^b z^c$$
Therefore it suffices to show that $x^a y^b z^c = 1$.

Your first and third equations give $y = x^{\frac {c-a}{b-c}}, z = x^{\frac{a-b}{b-c}}$. This gives us: 
$$x^a y^b z^c = x^a x^{\frac {c-a}{b-c}\times b} x^{\frac{a-b}{b-c}\times c} = x^{a + \frac{bc-ba+ca-bc}{b-c}} = x^{a-a} = x^0 = 1 $$

QED.

Comment: Excellent. From this it also follows that $(xyz)^{a+b+c}=1$ and therefore $xyz = 1$ or $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: Really nice! I wa thinking that it wasn't possible! +(1). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Given:
$$\dfrac{\log x}{b-c}=\dfrac{\log y}{c-a}=\dfrac{\log z}{a-b}=\lambda$$
we have:
$$ x = e^{\lambda(b-c)},\quad y=e^{\lambda(c-a)},\quad z=e^{\lambda(a-b)}, $$
hence:
$$x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b}\cdot z^{a+b-c} = \exp\left(\lambda\cdot\sum_{cyc}\left(b^2-c^2-a(b-c)\right)\right)=\exp(0)=1.$$

Comment: It is interesting that when I wrote the answer, I was debating between using $t$ or $\lambda$ and decided in favor of $t$ to avoid additional typesetting. The interesting part is that how certain notations people always use, like for instance $\lambda$ in this case.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If you have to show that $$x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b}\cdot z^{a+b-c} = 1$$ taking logarithms of both sides means that you have to show that $$(b+c-a)\log(x)+(c+a-b)\log(y)+(a+b-c)\log(z)=0$$ Now, use what user17762 and Jack D'Aurizio answered.

Comment: Thank you i think it is much simpler way. but i wanted to know if i could proceed using the three equations that i derived..

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\log x}{b-c}$ is equal to $\log\left(x^{1/(b-c)}\right)$ regardless of what the base of the logarithm is.  Hence we have
$$
\log\left(x^{1/(b-c)}\right) = \log\left(y^{1/(c-a)}\right) = \log\left(z^{1/(a-b)}\right).
$$
Since the logarithm function is one-to-one, this entails
$$
x^{1/(b-c)} = y^{1/(c-a)} = z^{1/(a-b)}.
$$
Raising both sides of $x^{1/(b-c)} = y^{1/(c-a)}$ to the power $(b-c)(c-a)$ yields
$$
x^{c-a} = y^{b-c}
$$
and the other two equalities are derived similarly.

Comment: Yes I already derived that equalities. I wanted to proceed from there on ..

Comment: Sorry --- I stopped too early; maybe I'll be back in an hour or so to add something.

Answer (score 1):

First let's assume that there are no indeterminations:

$x > 0 \land y > 0 \land z > 0 \land a \neq b \neq c$

And we have to prove that $k = 1$ in:

$x^{b+c−a}⋅y^{c+a−b}⋅z^{a+b−c} = k$

Using the asker equations from cross multiplication:

$x^{b+c−a}⋅x^{a-c}⋅y^{a}⋅z^{a}⋅x^{a-b} = x^a⋅y^a⋅z^a = (xyz)^a = k$

From this method, we can also obtain:

$(xyz)^b = k$

and

$(xyz)^c = k$

But then:

$k^{\frac{1}a} = k^{\frac{1}b} = k^{\frac{1}c} \implies k = 1$

What's more:

$xyz = 1$

Answer (score 0):

The product of the three equalities you have given is:
$x^{c-a} y^{a-b} z^{b-c} = y^{b-c} z^{c-a} x^{a-b}$

Grouping similar variables together,
$(x^{c-a} x^{b-a}) (y^{a-b} y^{c-b}) (z^{b-c} z^{a-c}) = 1$
$x^{-2a+b+c} \times y^{a-2b+c} \times z^{a+b-2c} = 1$

Comment: Thanks but it isnt correct answer! Look at LHS of your final statement, and the equation to be proved. There is a coefficient of -2 where it should be -1

Comment: Have you considered the option that the proposed answer is not right?

Comment: Actually, you have demonstrated that another relation between $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$ must be valid: $x^{-a}y^{-b}z^{-c} = 1$.

Comment: Exactly! the question asked something else.