# Unable to solve logarithm question

Tags: logarithms

Given

$$\dfrac{a(b+c-a)}{\log a}=\dfrac{b(c+a-b)}{\log b}=\dfrac{c(a+b-c)}{\log c}$$

To prove:

$$a^bb^a=b^cc^b=c^aa^c$$

What i tried is

$$\log (a^z)=a(b+c-a)$$ and similarly for other two. I am unable to break this down further! please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252685/how-do-we-prove-this-logarithm),
$$\log a = \lambda\cdot a(b+c-a)$$
and so on give:
$$ b\log a +a\log b = \lambda\cdot\left(ab(b+c-a)+ab(a+c-b)\right)=2\lambda\cdot abc$$
that is symmetric in $a,b,c$, so by exponentiating the previous line
$$ a^b b^a = a^c c^a = b^c c^b $$
follows.

Comment: How do you find methods of proceeding? thank yo again very much!

Comment: Please tell how did you know how to proceed?

Comment: @TimKrul: since you have to prove that three quantities are the same, and they are given by cyclic shifts of the variables, the key is just to find a symmetric expression in $a,b,c$. Moreover, there are not so many ways to go from the first line to the last one.