# Find $a^{b+c} b^{c+a} c^{a+b}$ if $\frac {\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $\frac {\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}$, then what would be the value of $a^{b+c} \cdot b^{c+a} \cdot c^{a+b}$?
I'm unable to proceed.

Comment: See also [Given $\frac{\log x}{b-c}=\frac{\log y}{c-a}=\frac{\log z}{a-b}$ show that $x^{b+c-a}\cdot y^{c+a-b}\cdot z^{a+b-c} = 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1252685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \frac {\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}=k$

$\Rightarrow a=e^{k(b-c)}, b=e^{k(c-a)},c=e^{k(a-b)}$. Then the required value is $ e^{k(b^2-c^2)}. e^{k(c^2-a^2)}. e^{k(a^2-b^2)}=1$

Answer (score -1):

Let $$ \frac {\log a}{b-c}=\frac{\log b}{c-a}=\frac{\log c}{a-b}=k\tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, we get

$$\log{a}=k(b-c)\tag{2}$$

$$\log{b}=k(c-a)\tag{3}$$

$$\log{c}=k(a-b)\tag{4}$$

Let $$l=a^{b+c} \cdot b^{c+a} \cdot c^{a+b}$$

Taking $\log$ on both sides, we get 
 $$\log{l}=(b+c) \cdot \log{a}+(c+a) \cdot \log{b}+(a+b) \cdot \log{c}\tag{5}$$

Now, using $(2),(3)$ and $(4)$ in $(5)$, we get

$$\log{l}=k(b^2-c^2)+k(c^2-a^2)+k(a^2-b^2)=0\tag{6}$$

From $(6)$, we get $\boxed{l=e^0=1}$

Comment: Isn't this copying the other answer?

Comment: @Did Technically different as we find the value of $\log{l}$, from which we find the value of $l$. So this offers a different insight. Moreover, many answers on this site are copied from others, which don't offer any insight on how to approach the problem. Still they are voted upon and praised by some members of this community. Why are they not criticised?

Comment: @Did To validate my claim see Muralidharan's answer posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860187/proof-of-the-square-root-inequality/1860192?noredirect=1#comment3809294_1860192) and many similar examples. Thus, I will not delete this answer, if that one is not deleted.