# Proof of the square root inequality $2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}$

Tags: inequality, radicals

I stumbled on the following inequality: For all $n\geq 1,$
$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}.$$
However I cannot find the proof of this anywhere.
Any ideas how to proceed?

Edit: I posted a follow-up question about generalizations of this inequality here:
[Square root inequality revisited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860326/square-root-inequality-revisited)

Comment: everytime you see $(n+1)^a - n^a$ think to $a \int_n^{n+1}x^{a-1}dx$

Comment: See also [Proof of inequality $2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2(\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1})$ using induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263115/proof-of-inequality-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrtn-2-sqrtn) 
and [Proof by Induction: $2(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139563/proof-by-induction-2-sqrtn1-sqrtn-frac1-sqrtn-2-sqrtn).
It can also be found as the first step in [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211973/estimating-partial-sums-sum-n-1m-frac1-sqrtn/1211980#1211980)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence:
$$ 2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}= \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
as well as
$$ 2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}=\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Answer (score 10):

$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}=2\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)=$$
$$=\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt n<\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\Leftrightarrow\sqrt n< \sqrt{n+1}$$

Answer (score 7):

\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n} &= 2\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \\
&= 2\frac{1}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} \\
&< \frac{2}{2\sqrt{n}} \text{ since } \sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
Similar proof for the other inequality.

Comment: I think this is a copy of Roman83 's answer.

Comment: I saw the answer only after I posted mine.

Comment: 5 minutes time lag for a nearly copied answer is not accepted, even if you are on a slow network. This way someone can answer any question on this site, claiming they saw it only after their answer was posted.

Comment: @Roby5 - calm down. It usually takes far more than 5 minutes to compose even a short post like this one. Don't berate people because someone else has the same basic idea (very common at this level of mathematics) and happened along a few minutes earlier. Such posts are only unacceptable when the later poster clearly had time to see the other post before they started their own.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$. Using [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) we get
$$\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n} = f'(c)$$
for some $c \in (n, n+1)$. Equivalently
$$2\sqrt{n+1} - 2\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt c}.$$
Since $c>n$, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt c} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$
therefore
$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n} < \frac 1{\sqrt n}.$$

Right inequality can be proved in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3):

As $\sqrt n>0,$

$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\iff2\sqrt{n(n+1)}-2n<1$$
$$\iff2\sqrt{n(n+1)}<2n+1$$

Squaring we get
$$4(n^2+n)<(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1\iff 1>0$$ which is true.

Can you follow the same method for the other inequality?

Comment: Yes, for sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n-1}\iff\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\lt\frac 12\lt n-\sqrt{n^2-1}$$
 Put $X=n+\frac 12$ and $Y=n-\frac 12$ so you get the evidences 
$$\sqrt{X^2-\frac 14}\lt X\iff X^2-\frac 14\lt X^2$$ and $$\sqrt{Y^2-\frac 14}\lt Y\iff Y^2-\frac 14\lt Y^2$$